# How to start a Windows service using powershell in a .net core application?

Tags: .net, powershell, windows-services

I have a .net application where I want the ability to start and stop a Windows service running on the same computer. I was able to pull back the service's status using get-service without a problem, but doing start-service doesn't work. No error, just doesn't do anything. I tried this first without using the async Invoke option so that it looked more like the function at the bottom. When debugging locally, it does not work and does not error.

```
using System.Management.Automation;

        private async static Task EditService(string serviceName, string command)
        {
            using (PowerShell PowerShellInst = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                //PowerShellInst.AddCommand(command).AddParameter("Name", serviceName);
                //I tried surrounding serviceName in quotes (but it has no spaces)
                PowerShellInst.AddScript("Start-Service -Name " + serviceName);

                await PowerShellInst.InvokeAsync();
            }         
        }
```

Getting service status (this works):

```
 public static string GetServiceStatus(string serviceName)
        {            

            using (PowerShell PowerShellInst = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                PowerShellInst.AddScript("Get-Service " + serviceName);

                Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInst.Invoke();

                if (PSOutput == null || PSOutput.Count == 0)
                    return "Unknown";
                else
                    return PSOutput.First().Properties["Status"].Value.ToString();                
            }            
        }
```

Comment: First thing I'd try is to use the same syntax for `Get-Service` and `Start-Service`, in PowerShell both should work, but not sure in this wrapped scenario. So just remove the `-Name` part of `Start-Service` to rule that out.

Comment: @PMental this did not make a difference, so we can rule that out. Am wondering if it's a permissions thing like the answer by transformer suggests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you don't have permissions, one option is to set the execution policy

```
//in powershell
 powershell.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy").AddArgument("Unrestricted")
.AddParameter("Scope","CurrentUser");

//or using the command prompt like so:
 string powerShellCmd = "/c powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted C:\somePowerShellScript.ps1";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe",powerShellCmd);
```

you can get the current user like so

```
WindowsIndentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

optionally try the new Host Builder, a new addition with .Net Core native, i.e. *without* topshelf

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWindowsService()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
            {
                // configure the app here.
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });
```

Comment: ExecutionPolicy can block scripts from running, but doesn't differentiate between different CmdLets and doesn't block shell code. If `Get-Process` works then the  ExecutionPolicy is fine for this scenario.

Comment: The Host Builder stuff is a bit greek to me so I'm going to focus on the permission concept first (and try the command prompt idea) although I'm very curious about it

Comment: Solved- it was a permissions thing. The IIS website's Application Pool Identity was not able to start/stop services but when I changed it to a service account with admin rights, this all worked. I did not have to add any of the code from this answer, what I originally had worked. But I discovered along the way that the ServiceController class is another option for this if I don't want to use Powershell.

Comment: you can change the line `.AddParameter("Scope","CurrentUser");` and replace the your user, it will run under that with the permissions. happy it works